# External display stuck at 30hz

Tags: display

My external display only has a 30HZ option...., what's up with that?
How can I make it 60?

Running Juno 5.0 on MP late 2015

---

It just seems to work now, I guess an update was posted :?

Comment: Post your external display specs or model. Also, did you try setting it manually using `xrandr`?

Comment: thanks for teaching me this command

Comment: No problem! If you write `man xrandr` it will explain how the command works.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; **Triple check that your cable supports 60Hz.**

Having struggled with this issue for a while now, I would like to point out that it is not you, not the monitor, not Linux but very likely the cable. A few months ago, I have even brought a perfectly fine, brand new 4K monitor back to the store because I thought I could not use it (30Hz is just unacceptable if you are doing 3D work). I spent evenings messing with `xrandr`, all to no avail. The guy at the store ensured me the cable was fine, but as it turns out, it was not.

This morning, I received a new USB-c to HDMI cable that explicitly supports 60Hz (it even says so on the USB-c plug). Just plugged it in and the issue is fixed. Even the monitor's 2.2 Gamma is displayed more accurately; I had it set to 2.6 with the other cable to get any depth in the blacks. I am using a Dell XPS 13 9370 with a 27" 4K Philips monitor (276E8VJSB) and elementary OS 5.0 Juno.

[image]